# How create custom widgets globally accessible in qt designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have created custom widgets as per the documentation in http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-designer-worldtimeclockplugin-example.html. And I added the generated dll in qt/Tools/Qt Creator/bin/plugins/designer and I was able see the custom widgets in the designer .

I want to use those custom widgets in the .ui file across the any .ui files globally but when I use those I get error stating cannot find mycustomwidget.h file in generated moc ui files. What extra step should I do to incude my custom widgets globally ? I have looked in [QtUiLoader](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/quiloader.html) and [QtPluginLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html) but I don't where to put those ?

Comment: you are confusing the concepts, if you have a widget plugin then you must have a custom widget and that custom widget must have its own dll different from the plugin, ie you must have at least 2 dlls: a dll of the custom widget + headers and another dll of the plugin, then in your main project you only have to link the dll of the custom widget since Qt designer handles the plugin.

Comment: In the next repo I have an example https://github.com/eyllanesc/QhPlugins

Comment: Yes I have custom widget and widget plugins both in one project and I place the generated dll in the right location to use it in Qt Designer. Why do dll is needed?

Comment: Do you know what a dll is? If you do not know, there are many posts in SO and on the internet. The example of Qt is dummy but it is not correct, you must have an exclusive project for the personlized widget, another project for the plugin and another project where you use the custom widget through the plugin, check the example of github that I have provided.

Comment: I meant why 2 dlls can't plugins and custom widgets wrapped in a single dll.

Comment: the plugin is for Qt Designer (it is only to be able to see the widget in Qt Defigner) instead the custom widget is for your application, you could have both together but that would involve having a heavier executable (ie for your application the plugin is garbage after the deployment so it is not necessary to be part of the executable).

Comment: I was looking to drag and drop my custom widgets in forms/ ui files and actually visually see the effect when I change the properties of it so thought of using it in one dll